# cache.writeFragment method in graphQL apollo library doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to add a property to an object already in cache.
I have added local resolver and in that i'm doing this.

```
cache.writeFragment({
  id: gid.toString(),
  fragment: gql`
    fragment queues on Group {
      queuesList
    }
  `,
  data: {
    queuesList: ["test"],
    __typename: "Group"
  }
});
```

This writes an object to cache and does not add a property to object of given Id.
I don't understand where does fragment fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was doing it wrong.
I was giving fragment wrong id, I had to pass the object keys in cached data.
That is. `id: Group:${gid.toString()}`

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#generating-unique-identifiers

Hope this helps anyone in same situation.